# Need Help on creating a Database on Small Basic

Tags: smallbasic

Just need general directions on where to start a database on small basic. i saw a guy do it but his instructions were quite confusing. i've been programming for a month now, so I'm new. can someone give me more or less an idea on where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make an array and then make a do a program where it writes to a text file using

```
FilePath = "C:\temp\TempSubdirectory\my.txt"
TextWindow.WriteLine("Write Content = " + 
File.WriteLine(FilePath, 1, "Shakespeare was a great writer."))
TextWindow.WriteLine("Append Content = " + 
 File.AppendContents(FilePath, "He wrote many plays."))
TextWindow.WriteLine("Read Content = " + 
 File.ReadContents(FilePath))
```

Comment: so the "filepath under file.writeline means it writes to the filepath you assigned, In this case my.text. right?

Comment: right. you rewrite the path as your path to the specific file. in this case, i went into the c drive, went to temp, then temp sub etc

Comment: the mt.text is a textfile, like notepad, can you call thaqt anything you want, ex. Employee.txt, or ilovebarney.txt. right?

Comment: yeah. txt is a text file. my.txt is a file, but you have to change it so it matches your criteria.